# By changing the order of integration, show $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x) \, dx \, dy = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\ f(x) \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Question:**
>   Show that if $f(x)$ is a continuous function, then:
>   $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x) \, dx \, dy = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x)\ f(x) \ dx$$

How can this be done? I was taught to visualise double integrals as either a summation of horizontal or vertical strips but I am unsure as to how to apply that idea to this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Cauchy's repeated integral formula ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to visualize the space you are integrating over. To do this draw out the Cartesian plane and try to shade in the space indicated by the integrals.

Since dy is on the outside and dx is on the inside you will be drawing using horizontal strips. The strips start y=0 and finish at y=1 (as indicated by the outer integral) and they go across as far as the y value at that point. For example the strip that starts at (0,0.5) will go horizontally across and end at (0.5,0.5). Once you do this for all the strips you can see the region indicated is a triangle with sides x=0, y=1 and y=x.

you now need to draw this with vertical strips. To begin you need to see what range the vertical strips are over, in this case it is from 0 to 1. You want the strip to start at whatever value x takes at this point and end when they reach 1 so they go from x to 1.

so to answer the question directly:

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} f(x) dx dy = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} f(x) dy dx 
= \int_{0}^{1} (1-x) f(x) dx$

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The area you're looking for is the one highlighted in the image below.[image]

Your integral integral is one that runs from x=0 to x=y, the external one runs from y=0 to y=1.

Using Cauchy's repeated integral formula.

The internal integral runs from y=0 to y=1 and the external one runs from x=0 to x=y.

You get $\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x}^{y=1} f(x)dydx$

Can you finish the rest?